# Why would you private encapsulate a private constant?

Tags: ruby, constants, private, encapsulation

I ran into this code:

```
class Foo < Bar
  SM_CONSTANT = { 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B' }.freeze
  private_constant :SM_CONSTANT

  private

  def some_constant
    SM_CONSTANT
  end
```

I cannot figure out the purpose of **encapsulating a private constant** in a **private method**. Why would I do this?

Comment: Why a private constant? Ask the developer. Why a method that returns this constant? So that you can override it.

Comment: I can understand a public encapsulation... but a private encapsulation doesn't make sense to me. Especially if it's just returning the constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `private_constant` is to prevent other code from accessing the constant directly.

`some_constant` might return the constant today, but it's not obligated to do that. If programming-by-contract then it's obligated to return a hash in that form, the origin of which is irrelevant.

For example, you have that code today, but what about tomorrow it evolves to:

```
class Foo < Bar
  SM_CONSTANT = {
    a: { name: 'A', priority: 2 },
    b: { name: 'B', priority: -1 }
  }.freeze
  private_constant :SM_CONSTANT

private
  def some_constant
    SM_CONSTANT.map { |k,o| [ k.to_s, o[:name] ] }.to_h
  end
end
```

Where the internals have completely changed but to outside code nothing has, the same calls produce the same results. This is why encapsulation is important. It gives you the freedom to iterate and rework code within a particular context without concerning yourself about breaking other things.

If code accessed `SM_CONSTANT` directly it'd have to be re-written to accept this new structure.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the private constant concept also extends to classes and modules, not just data. Keeping these encapsulated as private protects the implementation from external prying and frees the design to be able to evolve without breaking client code.